# Why python kivy,graphics resizable width,and height doesn't work

Tags: python, kivy

I wanted to set resizable value to 0, it didn't work, i can still resize it,then i tried to run the code from cmd (i use VS Code), it worked, but i wanted to set resizable value to 1 again, it didn't work again. The same problem with graphics width and height, i can't set them, it only works with Window.size, but i dont understand why width and height doesn't work succesfully.

```
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
Config.set('graphics','resizable',1)
Config.set('graphics','width',300)
Config.set('graphics','height',600)

class Greed(GridLayout):
    pass

class Container(BoxLayout):
    def calc(self):
        if self.tin.text:
            self.result.text=str(eval(self.tin.text))
    def clear(self):
        self.tin.text=''
        self.result.text=''
class MyApp(App):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyApp,self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def build(self):
        return Container()
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

and the .kv file

```
<Container>
    tin:ti_text
    result:result_text
    bone:buttonone
    orientation:'vertical'
    background_normal:""
    padding:25,0,25,25
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'background.png'
    
    Label:
        id:ti_text
        text:""
        size_hint:1,0.2
        font_size:20
    Label:
        id:result_text
        text:''
        size_hint:1,0.2
        font_size:20
    Greed:
        padding:0,0,0,15
        rows:5
        spacing:10
        
        Button:
            font_size:17
            id:buttonone
            text:'1'
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        Button:
            font_size:17
            text:'2'
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        Button:
            font_size:17
            text:'3'
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        Button:
            font_size:17
            text:'+'
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        Button:
            text:'4'
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        Button:
            text:'5'
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        Button:
            text:'6'
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        Button:
            text:'-'
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        
        Button:
            text:'7'
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text

        Button:
            text:'8'   
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17 
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        Button:
            text:'9'   
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        Button:
            text:'/'   
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        Button:
            text:'Clear'   
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'  
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:root.clear()
   
        Button:
            text:'0'   
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'  
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
   
        Button:
            text:'*'
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
        Button:
            text:'='
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:root.calc()

        Button:
            text:'.'   
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'  
            background_color:'#FF7B2924'
            font_size:17
            on_release:ti_text.text+=self.text
```

Comment: Try putting the Config.set before all the other kivy imports.

Comment: @inclement yeah it actually works, thanks :)